# Active Directory Failover with external DNS

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, domain, active-directory

I have redundant Windows Server 2008R2 Domain Controllers, all OUs and objects are being replicated between them properly.  Whenever I take down the primary Domain Controller none of my clients can authenticate.  I believe this is related to DNS since our DNS & DHCP are run off a Linux box.

How do I set up my domain so if my primary DC fails, it starts using the secondary?  Is this a configuration that needs to be done in DNS, on my client machines, or on the DC?

Answer (score 1):

Normally when there are multiple DCs in an AD domain, all of them are configured as nameservers for that domain and all of them are listed in NS and SRV records for the DNS domain. If the IP addresses of DCs are configured as the primary and secondary DNS servers on the clients then taking down one of DCs does not ruin anything.

From your question I understand that in your configuration the client machines have the Linux box configured as the only DNS server. Please take a look at _msdcs, _sites, _tcp and _udp subdomains of your DNS domain. I suppose they contain SRV records only for the first DC. Create proper records for the other server and everything will work as expected. [Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/cc759550(v=ws.10).aspx) you can find detailed information on required DNS records. You can also check the DNS records on DC's DNS server and copy them to you Linux box.